# How can I get Mathematica to show me how to integrate an integral?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, free-form-input

I tried using the free input to show me how to integrate the following integral but it didn't show me the steps.

> Solve with steps the integral of x*(2*a^2)*arccos(x/(2*a))-(x^2/2)*sqrt(4a^2-x^2) in the interval [0,a]

How to make Mathematica show me the steps?

Comment: I think this forum is for the Wolfram Mathematica language and not the Wolfram Alpha language. The Wolfram alpha language uses free format, English like, but Wolfram Mathematica language uses exact strict syntax which is well documented. You might want to try asking about the Wolfram alpha language in the Wolfram community forum, they have special forum for it.  [community.wolfram.com](http://community.wolfram.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Comment: I would have submitted this as an answer however it was already closed. What could help you is http://www.integral-calculator.com, it shows all the steps to your integration.

Answer (score 3):

Not even Wolfram|Alpha called from Mathematica has a step-by-step solution.

[image: WAQ]

#### Update

Mathematica has no problem with ***evaluating*** the integral.

```
Integrate[2 x a^2 ArcCos[x/(2 a)] - (x^2/2) Sqrt[4 a^2 - x^2], {x, 0, a}]
```

> `1/24 a^3 (-4 a + Sqrt[a^2]) (3 Sqrt[3] - 4 π)`

It just isn't going to give you a step-by-step solution.

Comment: It's from some exercise in statistical mechanics, I wouldn't be suprised that there's no solution to this problem. :-)

Comment: @Alan. See update.